# Deploy webservice from Team Foundation Server to IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net, deployment, tfs

I have locally made a simple helloworld web service (.asmx) that I want to test.

I have an enviroment where I already have it uploaded to the Team Foundation server, in `NAME\CustomerApplications\TestService\TestService\service.asmx` (the whole project is located in that structure).

The TF server and the IIS server are on the same machine.

Now, how do I deploy service.asmx file so I locally can get a path to the service like this: `http://serverip/../service.asmx`?

Comment: I would highly suggest you get in touch with your TFS administrator.  They should help you figure out how to properly get a tfs build and deployment working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "simplest" way to get an asp.net website/service working (manually) in IIS is to do the following:

1. Create a folder for it under `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` (assuming that you have your web root pointing there).
2. Copy all the `service.asmx`, `.config` files and the `bin` folder into the folder (assuming that you've compiled it at least once so that the `bin` folder contains dependencies and the compiled product of your service, i.e. the `service.asmx.cs` file)
3. Use "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager" to navigate down to MACHINE NAME > Sites > Default Web Site > TheNameOfTheFolderCreatedInStep1
4. Right-click on the folder and choose "Convert to Application"
5. Choose the appropriate application pool by clicking on the "Select..." button (i.e. .net 2.0 or .net 4.0)
6. Click "OK"

You should now be able to navigate to `http://serverip/FolderNameCreatedInStep1/service.asmx`.

Comment: Seems I cant do it like that. Your directions seems to work but i get "The file you are attempting to save or retrieve has been blocked from this Web site by the server administrators."